# Why Assistant preview fails?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, constraints

my assistant editor show me the right way I want my apps look like in big screen, but in the emulator or real device isn't the desirable results. Why? That's only an example, i Will this behavior in all my view controllers.
NO, simulators hasn't the zoom mode feature so It can't be zoom mode.

RIGHT assistant editor:

[image]

WRONG simulator behavior:

[image]

Comment: You need to include a launch image (or use a .xib) for this device size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assistant preview doesn't fail, but the simulator zooms your app (you can see it at the size of the status bar).

You probably did not include a launch image for 4,7" and 5" screen devices. If the app can't find these launch images, it will run the same as on a 4" screen and zoom it to fit the device.

The assistant editor does not look for those images, as it's simply a render of your storyboard with the constraints you set.

Add the launch images for the 4,7" and 5" screens and the app will look fine on the simulator. You can also use a .xib file to generate a launch image for iOS 8+.

Comment: Wow, amazing. Can I have some links or tutorial of Launch Images? first time I heard about that.

Comment: You could start with [Apple's documentation on launch images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html), and then search the web for tutorials. I'm confident you will find a ton of infos on this subject.